# Initialising a std::string from a character

Tags: c++, string, initialization, char

There doesn't seem to be a standard constructor so I've taken to doing the following

```
void myMethod(char delimiter = ',')
{
    string delimiterString = 'x';
    delimiterString[0] = delimiter;
    // use string version ...
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`std::string` has a constructor that will do it for you:

```
std::string delimiterString(1, delimiter);
```

The 1 is a `size_t` and denotes the number of repetitions of the `char` argument.

Comment: There's no need to change the signature to constify something - &delimiter is a char * which is convertible to a const char * automatically. const_cast is only needed to _remove_ constness.

Comment: `&delimiter` won't work since the resulting `char*` will not be null-terminated.

Comment: However the iterator constructor can be used - std::string s(&delimiter, &delimiter + 1)

Comment: Wow, I am totally full of fail tonight. In my defence I prefer references to anything involving pointers or the address-of operator, but that was a real newbie mistake on my part. The iterator constructor example is hilariously overwritten, though.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient, but it does show up at the top of Google, and it took a while for me to realize the answer. Also the fill constructor mentioned in the other answer is not intended for this. It occurred to me that since `std::string` AKA `std::basic_string<char>` accepts string literals which are `char *`s just as a `char []` does, it can accept a `char` just like a `char []` would.

Standard initialization of `char []` with `char`(s); where `ch` is a variable or constant of type `char`:

```
char        chPtr[] = {ch, '\0'}; // Will continue out of bounds without terminator
std::string str     = {ch};       // Wont continue out of bounds (1)
// Also: std::string str{ch};     // operator= is optional
```

Note 1: `string` doesn't use `\0` as a string terminator, instead holding it as just another character.

Also note that casting it to a `char *` wont work:

```
std::string str     = (char*)ch;  // Breaks All Output
```

For your testing convenience: https://onlinegdb.com/sEl5BoBGx

Comment: I was having trouble to compare a string with a char variable but solved with: `std::string("A") == std::string({charVar, '\0'})`, thx!!! (and nice online gdb tip!)